# bootstrap mobile menu not scrolling instead the background is scrolling

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, menu, toggle

i have a website done in bootstrap, the menu is working fine in desktop

```html
<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#navbar-menu" aria-expanded="true">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span style="font-size: 10px;width:100%;float: left;"><b>menu</b></span>
</button>
```

now when i loading it mobile, and open the menu, its not scrolling so i am not able to see the options in the dropdown, instead the background is scrolling, i searched and saw an answer in google like below:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  height: 150vh; // <-- This will fix the collapse animation
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   padding-right: 17px; // <-- Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

but still the menu is not scrolling and the background is scrolling. can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, this is my live url [enter link description here](http://btp.molugu.com/)

thanks in advance

Comment: I try you website with my Samsung S8 and google dev, in all two dropbox menu work.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, i just fixed it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i finally got a fix for this, i gave hieght for the menu and gave overflow scroll

```html
.navbar-nav {
  
 max-height:400px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `navbar-nav-scroll` class to the existing `navbar-nav` class, that will solve all scrolling issue.